# How to fix multiple modal screens and one not showing

Tags: html

Im creating two pop up modals and one should show social media and the other will soon be a different modal but i cannot test it as it wont load when i try run it.

Ive already tried to edit the ID's and roles but they dont seem to make a difference

```
<button class="flex-c-m s1-txt2 size3 how-btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subscribe">
    Social Media
</button>

<br>
<button class="flex-c-m s1-txt2 size3 how-btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reps">
    Contact a Rep
</button>
```

```
    <!-- Modal 1 -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="subscribe" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="modal-subscribe where1-parent bg0 bor2 size4 p-t-54 p-b-100 p-l-15 p-r-15">
                <button class="btn-close-modal how-btn2 fs-26 where1 trans-04">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i>
                </button>

                <div class=" m-lr-auto">
                    <h3 class="m1-txt1 txt-center p-b-36">
                        <span class="bor1 p-b-6">WHERE CAN I GO NEXT?</span>
                    </h3>

                    <p class="m1-txt2 txt-center p-b-40">
                        Follow us for updates now!
                    </p>
                            <br>
                            <div class="social-btns">
                                <a class="btn facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn google" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn dribbble" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn skype" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <br>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <!-- Modal 2 -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="reps" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="documentt" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="modal-reps where1-parent bg0 bor2 size4 p-t-54 p-b-100 p-l-15 p-r-15">
                <button class="btn-close-modal how-btn2 fs-26 where1 trans-04">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i>
                </button>

                <div class=" m-lr-auto">
                    <h3 class="m1-txt1 txt-center p-b-36">
                        <span class="bor1 p-b-6">WHERE CAN I GO NEXT?</span>
                    </h3>

                    <p class="m1-txt2 txt-center p-b-40">
                        Follow us for updates now!
                    </p>
                            <br>
                            <div class="social-btns">
                                <a class="btn facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn google" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn dribbble" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                                <a class="btn skype" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <br>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I should be getting a modal popup when selecting the 'contact a rep' button

Answer (score 0):

First from what I see on your code you need to make button `data-target` to your modals.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subscribe">
  Social Media
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reps">
  Contact
</button>
```

Second, also make sure you have jQuery and other dependency (bootstrap) script linked in your HTML file.

Comment: Still not changed anything, all the buttons are linked to the modal pop up but the contact one still does not seem to want to show.

Comment: I guess you are not using bootstrap modal, is there any css framework you are using?